# Access a YouTube Clip's start and end point

Tags: youtube

## Goal:

I am trying to find the start and end point of a YouTube Clip.

The URL's for YouTube Clips appear to follow no logic other than they have:
`https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx` + 32 characters

For example, for a 15 second clip starting at the beginning of: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiXD4xVJM5Y

The link is: 
https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxU2HSeGL_NvmDJ-nQJrlLwllwMDBdGZFs

There is nothing in the URL that would suggest it starts at 0 seconds, last 15 seconds or comes from video ID `NiXD4xVJM5Y`.

From the HTML I was able to find the video id:

```html
<html>
...
<body>
...
<ytd-app>
...
<div#content.style-scope.ytd-app>
...
<ytd-page-manager#page-manager.style-scope.ytd-app>
...
<ytd-watch-flexy class="style-scope ytd-page-manager hide-skeleton" video-id="NiXD4xVJM5Y"...>
```

But I cannot find the start point, end point, and/or duration.

Ideally, I would use a Python package to read the HTML, get the start and end point or get the start point and determine the end point by adding the duration.

Maybe I need to use YouTube Data API? I am inexperienced in YouTube's APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available through the API.

However, you could check the source code of the page - i.e.

```
https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxU2HSeGL_NvmDJ-nQJrlLwllwMDBdGZFs
```

and extract the data:

```json
[...] "startMs":"237223","endMs":"257223" [...]
```

Which corresponds to the start and end time of the clip.

and:

```json
[...] "clipConfig":{"postId":"UgkxU2HSeGL_NvmDJ-nQJrlLwllwMDBdGZFs","startTimeMs":"0","endTimeMs":"15000"} [...]
```

which corresponds to the duration of the said clip.

Comment: I have been using requests.get(link).content in order to get the source code. This has proven to be somewhat inconsistent, did you have a recommended way to get the source code?

Comment: [@futium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21798546/futium) I personally use `requests.get(link).text`.

Answer (score 1):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/d1fddf6907c9c3192e9da8d9d0d20fd007cd89bc/videos.php#L215-L229) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=clip&clipId=CLIP_ID, you will get the start and end time in milliseconds of a given clip in `item["clip"]`.

With the clip id [`UgkxU2HSeGL_NvmDJ-nQJrlLwllwMDBdGZFs`](https://www.youtube.com/clip/UgkxU2HSeGL_NvmDJ-nQJrlLwllwMDBdGZFs) you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UgkxU2HSeGL_NvmDJ-nQJrlLwllwMDBdGZFs",
            "clip": {
                "startTimeMs": 0,
                "endTimeMs": 15000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```